# Implementing an ajax call in clojurescript

Tags: ajax, jsonp, clojurescript

I'm new to clojurescript and would like to do a deeper dive by implementing a previously written application purely in clojurescript, but am at a loss with respect to to implement an ajax call. Can anyone point me to an example online or provide me with a code snippet or two?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**January 22, 2016 update**

Although it still works, the original answer is from a time when there was a general lack of ClojureScript solutions with more than 1 contributor. Rather than leveraging XhrIo directly, definitely consider using a well-maintained, feature-rich solution that wrappers it instead like [cljs-ajax](https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax), as suggested by Mikhail D below!

---

Okay, So given that Clojurescript leverages Google's Closure JavaScript library, a quick search of the Closure Documentation yielded xhrIo as the proper method for generating AJAX calls:

[Example using Closure's Asynchronous XMLHttpRequests with XhrIo](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/xhrio)

```
goog.net.XhrIo.send(url, opt_callback, opt_method, opt_content,
     opt_headers, opt_timeoutInterval)
```

A quick review of the Clojurescript source revealed the following function:

[From src/cljs/clojure/browser/net.cljs in clojure / clojurescript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/cljs/clojure/browser/net.cljs)

```
(defn xhr-connection
  "Returns an XhrIo connection"
  []
  (goog.net.XhrIo.))
```

So something along the lines of this should have the intended results:

```
(def xhr xhr-connection)

(defn myCallback [replyValue] 
  ... Do Something with replyValue
  ... for example: (someJsonFunc (.getResponseJson (.target replyValue))))

(defn ajax-json [url]
   (.send xhr url myCallback))
```

For JSONP, you can do something similar using the goog.net.Jsonp. See the link for details:

[JSONP Closure API](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/class_goog_net_Jsonp.html)

Hope someone finds this helpful!

Comment: I'm a little confused: why does `(.send xhr url myCallback)` work? As far as I can tell `xhr-connection` is a function that returns a new `goog.net.XhrIo`, so why does `.send` work on it?

Comment: the trailing dot on goog.net.XhrIo.  makes it equivalent to `new goog.net.XhrIo()`

Answer (score 14):

An another viable option could be https://github.com/JulianBirch/cljs-ajax

Since it's designed for ClojureScript, the syntax looks clearer and simpler. It also supports a lot of features out of the box (for example: `transit`, `edn` and `json` formats).

Some examples from a README:

```
(ns foo
  (:require [ajax.core :refer [GET POST]]))

...

(GET "/hello" {:handler handler
               :error-handler error-handler})

(POST "/send-message"
    {:params {:message "Hello World"
              :user    "Bob"}
     :handler handler
     :error-handler error-handler})
```

Answer (score 6):

The way I did it is slightly different. I don't know why the way that Marc suggested in his answer didn't work for me. Hopefully this is also useful.

I used `goog.net.XhrIo` directly, rather than the `xhr-connection` wrapper.

```
(defn callback [reply]
    (let [v (js->clj (.getResponseJson (.-target reply)))] ;v is a Clojure data structure
        (your-function-here v)))

(.send goog.net.XhrIo url callback)
```

The main difference that I can see is that I've used `.-target` to get the property of the JSON object, rather than calling `target`.

It's worth noting that maps in `v` that have been created from JSON objects are keyed by strings not keywords.