# ClojureScript, JavaScript, AJAX Calls, Continuation Passing Style

Tags: clojurescript

I realize that Clojure specifically chose to not have continuations.

I am currently playing with ClojureScript.

I notice that in JavaScript's AJAX call protocol, I often pass a function to handle "what to do after the AJAX call returns."

This sounds very much like a continuation.

Is there some standard way to setup CPS in ClojureScript?

If not, what is the right way to handle AJAX call backs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Clojure (and ClojureScript) lack [**first-class continuations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation#First-class_continuations), unlike Scheme, but there's nothing stopping you from writing code in explicit continuation-passing-style. You're right, a JavaScript AJAX call that takes a function callback is similar.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554745/implementing-an-ajax-call-in-clojurescript) other question on SO for AJAX and ClojureScript, which points out how to use the Google Closure library, and is probably the easiest to start with "out-of-the-box".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out Ganelon microframework for Clojure (which I am author of).

There are no CPS there, but the general idea - that server-side AJAX callbacks can update client-side contents or execute client-side JavaScript is quite similiar to continuation-style web framework for Common Lisp - Weblocks.

Demo & docs for Ganelon are available at http://ganelon.tomeklipski.com/